# How to convert a for loop output to a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

For example:

```
for y,x in zip(range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2)):  
    print(x+y)
```

Returns:

```
0  
3  
6  
9
```

What I want is:

```
['0', '3', '6', '9']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `mylist = [(x+y) for x,y in zip(range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2))]`

Comment: Do you specifically want the answers as strings? If you want to do further arithmetic (including sorting) then it's best to keep them as numbers (they also use less RAM in numeric form); you can easily convert them to strings when outputing them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way for your understanding, without using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), is:

```
mylist = []
for y,x in zip(range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2)):
    mylist.append(str(x+y))
print mylist
```

Output:

```
['0','3','6','9']
```

Comment: Don't use class name `list` as variable name.

Answer (score 8):

Try this using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps)

```
>>>[x+y for y,x in zip(range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2))]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>>[str(x+y) for y,x in zip(range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2))]
['0', '3', '6', '9']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate list dynamically:

```
print [str(x+y) for x, y in zip(range(0,4,1), range(0,8,2))]

['0','3','6','9']
```

This technique called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the for loops and use `map()` and import `add` from `operator`

```
from operator import add
l = map(add,range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2))
print l

[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

And if you want it as strings you could do

```
from operator import add
l = map(add,range(0,4,1),range(0,8,2))
print map(str, l)

['0','3', '6', '9']
```