# Not getting the entire list back when converting from binary to decimal

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert integers from my list to binary and vice versa. but for some reason i'm only getting the last integer back and not the entire list.

```html
redChannelData = [46, 49, 50, 51, 53, 53, 54, 56, 59, 59, 60, 61, 62, 62, 64, 64, 65, 65]

for value in redChannelData:
    encoded = [bin(value)[2:]]
    print(encoded)

for binary in encoded:
    decoded = [int(binary ,2)]
    print(decoded)
```

Output:

```html
['101110']
['110001']
['110010']
['110011']
['110101']
['110101']
['110110']
['111000']
['111011']
['111011']
['111100']
['111101']
['111110']
['111110']
['1000000']
['1000000']
['1000001']
['1000001']
[65]
```

Comment: That's because every time you overwrite `encoded` with the current loop's value: `encoded = [bin(value)[2:]]`. The same goes also for `decoded`.

Comment: @game0ver ok so how do I fix that?

Comment: Use `append` or a list comprehension which is faster.

Comment: Try with this: `encoded = [bin(value)[2:] for value in redChannelData]`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a for loop output into a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390493/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-output-into-a-list-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for value in redChannelData:
    encoded = [bin(value)[2:]]
    print(encoded)
```

In the loop above, you are creating a single element list and printing it. When the loop is over, encoded has the last value which is 65. You can create encoded as an empty list and append the binary value in the loop.

Comment: Like this:
`encoded = []
for value in redChannelData:
    encoded1 = bin(value)[2:]
    encoded.append(encoded1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    with a list-comprehension     

        [bin(i)[2:] for i in redChannelData]  

        Out[32]:    

        ['101110',
         '110001',
         '110010',
         '110011',
         '110101',
         '110101',
         '110110',
         '111000',
         '111011',
         '111011',
         '111100',
         '111101',
         '111110',
         '111110',
         '1000000',
         '1000000',
         '1000001',
         '1000001']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.