# How to convert a for loop output into a python list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm new to Python, sorry for the level of this question.

This is my output (prices from a website). I'm wondering how to convert them into a list of `int`s

```
for price_list_items in price_list:
        for values in price_list_items:
            x= values.rstrip(' zł')
            print(x)
```

479 000
355 000
269 000
499 000
289 000

The desired result will like this [479 000,355 000,... ]. Also, I want to be able to perform basic with the values.
I found this thread [How to convert a for loop output into a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390493/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-output-into-a-list-python), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lista = []

for price_list_items in price_list:
        for values in price_list_items:
            x= values.rstrip(' zł')
            lsita.append(x)

lista = ['479 000', '350 000']
for idx, item in enumerate(lista):
        item = item.split()
        item = ''.join(item)
        lista[idx] = int(item)

print(lista)
```

> `~/python/stack$ python3.7 sum.py  [479000, 350000]`

Change your last line to `append` to `lista` instead of `print`. Now we have `lista = ['479 000', ...]` but we want `int`s to perform operations on.

So we can then `enumerate` our `list`, from there we can `split()` and `join()` to get to here `lista = ['479000', ...]` then we can just use `int(item)` and put them back into `lista` as `int`s

For fun we could do some `map` and just go from:

```
lista = ['479 000', '350 000']
lista = list(map(lambda x: int(''.join((x.split()))), lista))
```

Comment: Thank you vash_the_stampede. It will take some time to understand it but it works fine.

Comment: @Paul np I tried to detail it best I could if any questions just ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your string is meant to be a series of 6-digit numbers but both the individual number-parts, for lack of a better term, are split by spaces and the numbers themselves are split by newlines. The solution, therefore, is to remove the space in between number-parts, converting the result to an integer, like this:

```
int(part.replace(' ', '')) # Finds all instances of space and replaces them with nothing
```

Putting this in a list-comprehension, we have:

```
numbers = [int(l.replace(' ', '')) for l in str]
```

**UPDATE**

Since you've posted your code, I can give you a better answer.

```
[ int(v.rstrip(' zł').replace(' ', '')) for price_list_items in price_list for v in price_list_items ]
```

Comment: If the data was read from a file opened in text mode then line ending will usually get automatically converted to `\n`; more options are available via the `newline` arg to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @PM2Ring Correct. I wasn't sure how he got his data. It sounded like he already had it in from wherever he got and he was looking to get it into a `list` of `int`s from there

Comment: Fair enough, but it's probably safe to assume that he just has simple `\n` line endings. If his multi-line data is in a single string it can be split with `.splitlines`, which can get rid of the line endings. And if it's already in a list of lines, or is being being read line by line, then the line endings can be removed (along with any other trailing whitespace) by using `.rstrip`. BTW, your code has both `\r\n` and `\n\r`. You should probably fix that. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring question, we can convert these numbers to `ints` we know, but how is he going to be able to use these ints if we maintain the space between the two sets of 3 digits i.e `430 000` even if its `ints` shouldn't we eliminate that space

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I think the space might be a locale-specific format for numbers. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138047/when-writing-large-numbers-should-a-comma-be-inserted)

Comment: @Woody1193 no what I'm saying is, can't we assume he wants `ints` in a list to perform math on these `ints` if he has `430 000` he wont be able to perfrom math, we can give him `430000` no space and he can do math then

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Agreed. That's what my solution does

Comment: @Woody1193 of course , also while doing this, I wanted to use `map` I was curious could we perform mulitple functions to a list at the same time with `map`?.... Never mind just did a wild ass `map` for fun