# Importing multiple Excel files into multiple pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a for loop to import multiple Excel files into multiple dataframes.

I tried to do a `for` loop with two variables, where `f` represents the file's path and `i` represents a different dataframe ranging from 1 to `len(files)`, so dataframe would be named "1" and contain the Excel from the first path etc.

```py
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

for f, i in zip(files, np.arange(len(files))):
    i = pd.read_excel(f)
```

Instead it seems that I am getting only one dataframe named "i" containing only one of the Excel files.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to convert a for loop output into a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390493/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-output-into-a-list-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the scope of `i` is only inside the for-loop so you will never get the dataframe out of the loop with `i`. Second, you are using the variable `i` to loop, then assigning the dataframe to `i`, then looping with `i` again, and assigning to `i` again, overwriting `i` in every loop; that's the reason your are getting only the last excel data. Third, you cannot name an object with a number, that's the job for a variable.

I suggest a list of dataframes:

```
dataframes = [] # list of dataframes, empty at the begining

for f in files:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(f))
```

Now you can access to each individual dataframe calling its own variable `dataframes[0]`, `dataframes[1]`, `dataframes[2]`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do os.getcwd() first for the path. os.listdir() should work fine.

If the xlsx files are the only thing in your directory:

This would create a list of the dataframes, and then you can use `pd.concat` to combine them all if they are the same structure.

```
files = os.listdir()

dataframes = []
for file in files:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(file))

combined_dataframes = pd.concat(dataframes, sort=False)
```

OR

```
dataframe_series = pd.Series(dataframes)
```

The following would create a dictionary where the keys are named 'excel_file_1', 'excel_file_2' etc..

```
dataframes = {}
for i, file in enumerate(files):
    name = 'excel_file_' + str(i+1)
    dataframes[name] = pd.read_excel(file)
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this isn't exactly what I wanted to do, it still helps me!

Comment: What did you want to do?

Comment: This creates one dataframe with all the dataframes in it, I wanted to create separate variables which contain separately the dataframes.

Comment: The first example does that yes, only if you use `pd.concat()`. The first section of that will create a list of dataframes where you can access each of the dataframes by calling dataframes[0], dataframes[1].. etc.

Comment: There is no reason to create separate variables with each dataframe. You should be housing the dataframes in a single object, like a list or dictionary. Thats the proper way to do this.

Comment: Yes, figured out as much, I could then just slice and do whatever I want from the collective dataframe. Thanks a lot!